# SQL Server : SELECT DISTINCT [COL1] from {TABLE} WHERE [COL2] = 'A' AND [COL2] <> 'B'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct, multiple-records

I have to find a `SELECT DISTINCT [COL1] from {TABLE}` there can find all from [COL1] there have 'A' in [COL2] but not 'B' in [COL2]
In this case '3' and '4' should be the result

**TABLE**

```
   [COL1]      [COL2]
   ----        ----
   '1'          'A'
   '1'          'B'
   '1'          'C'
   '2'          'B'
   '2'          'C'
   '3'          'A'
   '3'          'C'
   '4'          'A'
   '4'          'D'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [COL1] from {TABLE} WHERE [COL2] = 'A' 
EXCEPT
SELECT [COL1] from {TABLE} WHERE [COL2] = 'B'
```

Or

```
SELECT [COL1]
FROM   {TABLE}
GROUP  BY [COL1]
HAVING MAX(CASE
             WHEN [COL2] = 'A' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) = 1
       AND MAX(CASE
                 WHEN [COL2] = 'B' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Ok, just asking as i haven't used EXCEPT much.

Comment: @jyparask - It's analogous to `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`. There is an `EXCEPT ALL` but not implemented in SQL Server.

Comment: I can't use EXCEPT, so I give the other example a try :-)

Comment: @LeifBramsing - Why can't you use `EXCEPT`? Are you on SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm not sure, but I think it's an old one :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [COL1]
FROM {TABLE} t1
WHERE t2.[COL2] = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM {TABLE} t2
    WHERE t2.[COL1] = t1.[COL1]
    AND t2.[COL2] = 'B'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [COL1]
    FROM   [TABLE]
    WHERE  [COL2] = 'B'
)
SELECT DISTINCT [COL1]
FROM   [TABLE]
WHERE  [COL2] = 'A'
AND    [COL1] NOT IN (SELECT [COL1] FROM MyCTE )
```